# Interaction between google mail and Google Sheets

Tags: email, google-apps, google-sheets-api

I want to know if there is an application that can allow an interaction between Google Mail and a Google Sheet.

I explain myself : 
I receive many e-mail from online forms and all the email are similar with the inormations about the customer I have to contact. I want to receive all the form into a Google Sheets that I can manage like a CRM.

Thank you for your help.

Regards,

Steve

Answer (score 0):

There are services that can assist with this and you can use custom scripts also. It can also depend on what type of platform you're using for the contact form.

[IFTTT](https://ifttt.com/recipes/136472-add-new-row-to-google-spreadsheet-based-on-email-contents) | [Zapier](https://zapier.com/zapbook/zaps/2618/add-new-rows-to-google-sheets-based-on-gmail-contents/) | [Script](http://www.i-programmer.info/projects/36-web/5381-gmail-spreadsheets-and-google-app-script.html)

Answer (score 0):

If the data is correctly formatted this one is an easy script to do exaclty that.

In google sheets, Tool >Script Editor >

```
    function sendEmails() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(' List');
  var last = sheet.getLastRow();
  for(var i=2;i<last+1;i++){}
  var firstName = sheet.getRange(i, 1).getValue();
  var email = sheet.getRange(i, 4).getValue(); // the second value is the column numbers , from left to right 1 to all 
  var message = 'Hola '+firstName+', message'; // Replace "Message" with your meesage and if you need to break lines use /n at the start of the new line 

  GmailApp.sendEmail(email, 'MPFC Schedule Assistant Bot',message);




}
```